# Date Pickers and custom display format

Tags: javascript, html, datepicker

I'm a bit stuck here. My application is a non-mobile database front-end, and I need a date field in my form formatted in 'my own way', that is "20-jan-2020", and an accompanying date picker.

- I cannot get the `<input "date" />` element to format my date value this way (or can I?)
- The picker itself is OK, but I cannot find a reliable way to open it from Javascript (or can I?). The idea was to use a hidden date input, and display the formatted value in a normal text input. Then invoke the picker of the hidden input from a button.
- I have been looking for some custom pickers around, but those I find are either designed for mobile (way too big), requires jscript/jquery (which I know nothing about), cannot format the date any better than the built-in one (or is there any?), or overrides the rest of the styling of my font end.

Suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 0):

With doing an input type you need to remember to put it inside the form tags like this,

```
   <form action="/action_page.php">
      <label for="birthday">Birthday:</label>
      <input type="date" id="birthday" name="birthday">
      <input type="submit">
   </form>
```

Hope this helped

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery UI datepicker. It provides well designed datePicker also with lots of options and events.

Try below code.

```js
var currentDate = new Date();
var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
     "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
];
    
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#datInput").val(formatDate(currentDate))
    
    $( "#hiddenDatePicker").datepicker({
      showOn: "button",
      buttonText: "day",
      onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
         var formattedDate = formatDate(new Date(dateText));
         $("#datInput").val(formattedDate);
      }
    });
    
 });
    
function formatDate(dt) {
   var day = dt.getDate();
   var month = monthNames[dt.getMonth()];
   var year = dt.getFullYear();
   
   return day + '-' + month + '-' + year;

}
```

```css
#hiddenDatePicker{
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<input type="input" id="hiddenDatePicker" class="datepicker" />
<input type="text" id="datInput"/>
```